# Up vs Right up - What's the difference?

Tags: prepositions

For example, it is the second more emphatic or just more words(unnecessary):

> She went **up** to the door
>
> She went **right up** to the door

Comment: "Right" in this case means that it's the thing she did right away. In the first sentence, she could do something on her way to the door. Another use of "right" would be "Water please. - Coming (right) up" which means straight away, without delay.

Comment: What's the context? The second version is more emphatic. It could imply that you expected her to stop at the gate, but she went right up to the [front] door.

Comment: @TrevorD I found these phrases in a german-learning book and i understood the german versions but not so much these ones

Comment: @MorganFR (Our comments were simultaneous.)  I agree that "right" can mean *right away*, *immediate*, etc., but I don't see how it can mean that is this example. In my mind, as I said, it adds emphasis, in the sense of "she went ***all the way to***  or ***as far as*** the door.

Comment: @WeaponX  If you're learning English, you might find our sister site [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) helpful.

Comment: @TrevorD what about "She was running fast and she went right up to the door", as opposed to "She took her time and went up to the door, glancing at the paintings on each side of the corridor..."?

Comment: @MorganFR No! IMHP, it would never be used that way in BrE.  In any case, that example is nothing to do with immediacy as in "she did it right away" (as in your former example): it's to do with 'didn't bother to stop first'.

Comment: She didn't pussy-foot.

Answer (score 2):

We can begin by comparing "She went to the door" and "She went **up** to the door." In the first case, we might assume that she is inside the house, though that is not necessarily true, but with "up" we probably assume that she is outside the house (or other building type) because "up" implies ["toward or near a point closer to the source or beginning of "](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/up), so there is probably a path of some sort. It's possible that "up" has an even more literal meaning here, and that she climbed some stairs to reach the door.

Then we can compare "She went up to the door" with "She went **right** up to the door." "Right" probably changes the meaning in two different ways, but without more context, we can't know which. One possibility is that "right" adds the sense of ["in the exact location, position, or moment" or "all the way"](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/right) according to our friends at Merriam-Webster, [among](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/right) [others](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/right). In this sense, she walked all the way to the door, she did not stop much more than a step away from it. If it opened outward suddenly, she would suffer an injury of some kind.

"Right" could also mean ["without delay, immediately"](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/right). In this sense, she drives up to the building, gets out of the car, and without pause goes to the door. We might imagine an angry or excited manner to her walk; something has happened that involves whoever is on the other side of that door and she is filled with a sense of urgency. Again, without more context, it's impossible to say that this is the correct meaning. Looking at the various dictionaries, however, suggests that this sense of "immediately" is slightly less common than the previous.

Answer (score 0):

I've always understood "right" in this context to mean something like "immediately adjacent to".  "I stood right next to her."  "It's right under the yellow book."  It may be an intensifier.